# Are questions about specific species allowed?

Tags: discussion

This refers to questions that concerns with pure information to individual species, where little thinking is needed from the answer-giver.

The question "where and how to capture freshwater planarian?" was in mind.

Comment: That particular question might be too localized, but maybe not, depending on how it's worded.